# How to apply pca() [Matlab] on high dimensional data

Tags: matlab, pca, dimensionality-reduction

I want to apply `pca()` function in `matlab` on data with `500 dimensions`. But pca() has a limit of only 99 dimensions. Do I have to write code for pca.

Comment: I just run this snippet and worked. `D = randn(1000,500);
[coeff,score,latent] = pca(D);` Are we in the same boat?